# Is there a filter option for matchLevel on here's autosuggest?

Tags: here-api, here-autocomplete

I just set up autosuggest but I only want street addresses returned, is there a parameter for filtering matchLevel?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this which will match your query.

```
http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=XXXX&app_code=YYYY&query=Pariser+1+Berl&beginHighlight=<b>&endHighlight=</b>&maxresults=1
```

for more details regarding parameters you can go through the below documentation 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/topics/resource-suggest.html

Happy Coding!

Comment: I was looking for something like resultType but only getting addresses instead of including regional results. This doesn't seem to be possible with Here and moved onto a different implementation. Thanks for your reply though!